# Will and future fact

Tags: future-tense, present-continuous

There is something I don't understand with the future simple.

My book says we can use it in this sentence:

> "In June we will bring out two new models"

Instead I  would say:

> "In June we are bringing out two new models"

(present continuous) because this is planned!

According to the book we should use the future simple because this is a future fact! Is it true? If yes can you give me (better) examples of future facts.

Comment: Can you tell us exactly which book this is, and exactly what it says?  That rule doesn't sound 100% correct to me, but I would like to know exactly what it says.

Answer (score 1):

For your example both work because you included the prepositional phrase "In June".  Without that phrase, the second sentence gives you no information about the timing of the event, while the first still tells you with certainty that it will happen at some point in the future:

"We will bring out two new models"

vs.

"We are bringing out two new models"

In general future fact sounds very certain, and implies something about the timing without any prepositions.  Consider the differences between:

"I will survive" versus "I am surviving". The first sounds reassured, while the second sounds like you're barely surviving.

"I will go on vacation" versus "I am going on vacation".  The first is clear that this is something that will happen in the future.  The second is unclear, it could mean you are leaving right now.